# Error while loading shared libraries: libhidapi-libusb.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

monero-gui-v0.13.0.3

Error while loading shared libraries: libhidapi-libusb.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

For this error on x64 Linux Mint/Debian/Ubuntu the fix is the below command

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev
```

Comment: Going to close this in favor of the thread I just created, which has a better overview in my opinion. Thanks for your report (added you as source).