# GUI / monerod v0.13.0.3 does not start on Linux because of "./monero-wallet-gui: error while loading shared libraries: libhidapi-libusb.so.0"

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, linux

GUI / monerod v0.13.0.3 does not start on Linux because of "./monero-wallet-gui: error while loading shared libraries: libhidapi-libusb.so.0". How do I resolve this particular issue?

Comment: I just installed libhidapi-libusb0 out of the software repository (Synaptic) in Ubuntu 16.04 and it works.

Comment: I came across this error and the "sudo apt-get install libhidapi-dev" fixed it for me. Thanks, Debruyne, as always!!!

Comment: (This should be a comment, not an answer, but my reputation won't allow me to do that...) I'm pretty sure `libhidapi-dev` is only required to build from source. To run the binary, you only need `libhidapi-libusb0`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## To run Monero Wallet GUI/daemon

First, this error is caused by the absence of the`libhidapi` library, which is required by Ledger. Two forms of this library exist, one each for use with the hidraw (USB/Bluetooth) and libusb (USB-only) backends, and the error message indicates that the latter is needed.

Fortunately, this error is quickly resolved by installing the package which includes it with your system's package manager. For the most common Linux distributions that would be as follows:

**Debian-based [.deb] (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, elementary OS, etc.):**

`sudo apt install libhidapi-libusb0`

**Fedora-based [.rpm] (Fedora, openSUSE, CentOS, PCLinuxOS, RHEL, etc.):**

`dnf install hidapi`

**Arch-based (Arch, Manjaro, Antergos, etc.):**

`pacman -S hidapi`

**Gentoo-based (Gentoo, Redcore, etc.):**

`emerge -atv dev-libs/hidapi`

**Slackware-based [.txz] (Slackware, VectorLinux, etc.):**

[Download package here](https://slackware.pkgs.org/14.2/slackonly-x86_64/hidapi-0.8.0_rc1-x86_64-1_slonly.txz.html)

`upgradepkg --install-new hidapi-0.8.0_rc1-x86_64-1_slonly.txz`

**Alpine Linux:**

`apk add hidapi`

---

## To build Monero Wallet GUI/daemon

If rather than simply trying to run the Monero wallet/daemon you were attempting to build it from source code, you would likely need an additional package which provides the header files for said library. The most common standard for those package names would be to append `-dev` to the packages listed above, however there are exceptions. Both Debian-based and Fedora-based distributions use the name `libhidapi-dev` in place of the packages specified above.

**Sources:**

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/9lcdme/preliminary_information_thread_regarding_the/e7ubtxp/
2. [Error while loading shared libraries: libhidapi-libusb.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10359/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libhidapi-libusb-so-0-cannot-open-shared)
3. https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/9ol2ic/gui_v01303_beryllium_bullet_released/e7vm7qj/